# Unit test for the method returning data read from database

Tags: unit-testing

I have a method which reads data from the database and then returns it. I'm wondering whether I should write unit tests for it or not. If so, how to do this? Since the data is always changing, I can't just hard code the expected value in unit tests. But if I read expected value from the database in unit tests, they look just like the method under test and it's hard to guarantee their correctness. I'm really confused by this problem. Really thx if you can help.

Comment: what exactly does your method do that you want to test?

Comment: @lockstock The method just reads a column of a table and then returns it as a list. It's so simple but hard to test (If I should).